# playing a sound through javascript when button has certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like a Javascript solution to play a certain sound when the text of a button has a certain value.

I haven't tried this type of functionality using jquery or javascript.  Can anyone guide me how to do it.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, but I guess you could read the value of the button and then insert a html5 audio element and play it. Another option would be a video or with flash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find a sound you like (for example on [this site](http://www.soundjay.com/beep-sounds-1.html)).

Put an `<audio>` element on your page.
Get your audio element and call the `play()` method:

```
document.getElementById('yourAudioTag').play();
```

Check out this example: http://www.storiesinflight.com/html5/audio.html

[This site](http://blog.gingertech.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/LCA_MM_AVProc2011/#slide6) uncovers some of the other cool things you can do such as `load()`, `pause()`, and a few other properties of the audio element.

When exactly you want to play this audio element is up to you. Read the text of the button and compare it to "no" if you like.

### Alternatively

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

SoundManager 2 provides a easy to use API that allows sound to be played in any modern browser, including IE 6+. If the browser doesn't support HTML5, then it gets help from flash. If you want stricly HTML5 and no flash, there's a setting for that, preferFlash=false

It supports 100% Flash-free audio on iPad, iPhone (iOS4) and other HTML5-enabled devices + browsers

Use is as simple as:

```
<script src="soundmanager2.js"></script>
<script>
// where to find flash SWFs, if needed...
soundManager.url = '/path/to/swf-files/';

soundManager.onready(function() {
    soundManager.createSound({
        id: 'mySound',
        url: '/path/to/an.mp3'
    });

    // ...and play it
    soundManager.play('mySound');
});
```

Here's a demo of it in action: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/christmas-lights/

Comment: hi @Joris how i can get sound of "No".           Thnaks

Comment: You will have to find a sound file (.wav for example) that sounds like what you want it to to sound like.

Comment: Try http://www.soundjay.com/beep-sounds-1.html

Comment: added the link to the answer